# Javascript to lock/turn iPhone off?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, automation, scripting

i’m messing around with the automation features on iOS and i’m putting some together that will prompt me with options of other things to do upon opening tiktok (instead of… deleting it)

right now i have a list that pops up when i open it, and when i click an option like “journal” it opens spotify so i can put my background music on

for some of my options like reading a book, i’d like to be able to select it and my phone immediately turns off

right now i have it set to return to the homescreen, but i found an option that allows me to run Javascript on a webpage

is it possible to write something that would turn my phone off? I understand this is a little convoluted when the power button is *right there* but it’s not for me, it’s for the adhd

Comment: Don't think this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript it's impossible. You can do it in java or kotlin.